# How to handle with merging large csv files in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a few files in csv.

example:
first.csv:

```
    a     b     c     d    pos   chrom
    31   412   544   233    44234  1
    23   4f3   515   141    551    2
    dsf  3rs   2321  512    51     5 
    123   22   123   5155   2355   1
   ...
```

second.csv

```
    a     Name     d    position   chrom
    31   dasf    233    34244      1
    23   faf     521    551        2
    dsf  gdsg    422    321        5 
    123  dsgg    5155   2355       1
    ....
```

Both have thousands of records. I need to find records with same position and then process it in another method.
So I tried to merge those frames by joining inner in pandas.

```
innerDF = pd.merge(first, second, how = 'inner', left_on = 'position', right_on='ars120_pos')
```

I got a Memory Error. Of course, I googling a problem and found a few answers bu I have a problem with them.

I won't use dask, coz every time I using it I got an differents error. I read it's a buggy.

I found chunksize tip here in pandas. I tried to use it:

```
first  = pd.read_csv('/home/iso/Desktop/Work/Map/Ill/first.csv',sep = ',', chunksize = 1000, iterator= True)

temp = None
temp_chunk = None
for chunk1 in first:
    second = pd.read_csv('/home/iso/Desktop/Work/Map/ARS/second.csv', chunksize = 1000, iterator = True)
    for chunk2 in second:
        temp_chunk = pd.merge(chunk1, chunk2, left_on = 'pos', right_on='position', how = 'inner')
        temp = pd.concat([temp, temp_chunk])
    finalData = temp.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```

But when I run it, the code is compiling a few hours and It looks like frozen.

Can tell me, someone, why second attempt dosen't work? I found it here on SO. And anyone can someone give me advice or link to best practice in that task?

Comment: Is this a many:many merge? If so, whats the duplicity? If you can't store the product in memory it doesn't matter how you split up the merge if you're trying to concat in the end...

Comment: @ALollz is correct.  It sounds like you are dealing with a large cartesian product.  Not sure of exactly what you are trying to do but If at all possible remove the duplicates on the columns that are being joined.  You can merge the result back to the original DataFrames creating a flag of the items that were found in both frames.